# Unity Game App runs fine on editor but crashes at startup on Android

Tags: unity, android, build-process, crash

```
edit> new log messages error from google play console with symbols attached>
Exceptions
#555 pc 0000000000516aa4 /data/app/com.BananaBananaGamesStudio.PandaInLove-uwkWI1KD8Ky8mqZVu3tIrQ==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: f906d698b5739e4c9b6fd97129c65207b1de60a9)
Native crash of com.BananaBananaGamesStudio.PandaInLove
at libc.scudo::Allocator<scudo::AndroidConfig, &(scudo_malloc_postinit)>::allocate(unsigned long, scudo::Chunk::Origin, unsigned long, bool)(AndroidConfig, &:4)
Native crash of com.BananaBananaGamesStudio.PandaInLove
#555 pc 0000000000516aa4 /data/app/com.BananaBananaGamesStudio.PandaInLove-iIA-AL9fmIJZKfg8FD7WXA==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: f906d698b5739e4c9b6fd97129c65207b1de60a9)
Native crash of com.BananaBananaGamesStudio.PandaInLove
#01 pc 00347a1a /data/media/0/Android/data/com.BananaBananaGamesStudio.PandaInLove/files/il2cpp/Metadata/global-metadata.dat
Native crash of com.BananaBananaGamesStudio.PandaInLove
```

I'm struggling for about two weeks on this: I made a game on the last months and it was running fine both on editor and on my Android phone. I made more levels and implemented Unity Ads with no errors on the editor. But now it crashs on the first seconds at my Android device. But stills runs fine on the editor. With Unity Android Logcat I got this:

```
> 01/30 23:01:46.457 31856 31856 Error Zygote accessInfo : 0 01/30 23:01:47.137 31856 31869 Error CRASH *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** 01/30 23:01:47.137 31856 31869 Error CRASH Version '2020.3.23f1 (c5d91304a876)', Build type 'Release', Scripting Backend 'il2cpp', CPU 'armeabi-v7a' 01/30 23:01:47.137 31856 31869 Error CRASH Build fingerprint: 'samsung/j5lteub/j5lte:6.0.1/MMB29M/J500MUBU1BRD1:user/release-keys' 01/30 23:01:47.137 31856 31869 Error CRASH Revision: '5' 01/30 23:01:47.137 31856 31869 Error CRASH ABI: 'arm' 01/30 23:01:47.137 31856 31869 Error CRASH Timestamp: 2022-01-30 23:01:47-0300 01/30 23:01:47.137 31856 31869 Error CRASH pid: 31856, tid: 31869, name: UnityMain >>> com.BananaBananaGamesStudio.PandaInLove <<< 01/30 23:01:47.137 31856 31869 Error CRASH uid: 10172 01/30 23:01:47.137 31856 31869 Error CRASH signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0xb2d5cff8 01/30 23:01:47.137 31856 31869 Error CRASH
r0 9ef603b0 r1 b7c46bc8 r2 b7c46bc8 r3 b2d5d03e 01/30 23:01:47.137 31856 31869 Error CRASH r4 9ef48fb0 r5 0000011e r6 b2d5d03f r7 0000008f 01/30 23:01:47.137 31856 31869 Error CRASH r8 b2d5d038 r9 99068f84 r10 99083a1c r11 b2d5d010 01/30 23:01:47.137 31856 31869 Error CRASH ip 9900ca7c sp b2d5d010 lr 9de33824 pc 9de33660 01/30 23:01:47.137 31856 31869 Error CRASH 01/30 23:01:47.137 31856 31869 Error CRASH backtrace: 01/30 23:01:47.137 31856 31869 Error CRASH #00 pc 002fb660 /data/app/com.BananaBananaGamesStudio.PandaInLove-1/lib/arm/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: b5c43ddd04c71984469ca752577c033162526da7) 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error CRASH Tombstone written to: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.BananaBananaGamesStudio.PandaInLove/files/tombstone_02 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime FATAL EXCEPTION: UnityMain 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime Process: com.BananaBananaGamesStudio.PandaInLove, PID: 31856 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION [UnityMain] 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime Unity version : 2020.3.23f1 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime Device model : samsung SM-J500M 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime Device fingerprint: samsung/j5lteub/j5lte:6.0.1/MMB29M/J500MUBU1BRD1:user/release-keys 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime Build Type
: Release 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime Scripting Backend : IL2CPP 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime ABI : armeabi-v7a 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime Strip Engine Code : true 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime Caused by: java.lang.Error: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime Version '2020.3.23f1 (c5d91304a876)', Build type 'Release', Scripting Backend 'il2cpp', CPU 'armeabi-v7a' 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime Build fingerprint: 'samsung/j5lteub/j5lte:6.0.1/MMB29M/J500MUBU1BRD1:user/release-keys' 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime Revision: '5' 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime ABI: 'arm' 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime Timestamp: 2022-01-30 23:01:47-0300 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime pid: 31856, tid: 31869, name: UnityMain >>> com.BananaBananaGamesStudio.PandaInLove <<< 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime uid: 10172 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0xb2d5cff8 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime
r0 9ef603b0 r1 b7c46bc8 r2 b7c46bc8 r3 b2d5d03e 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime r4 9ef48fb0 r5 0000011e r6 b2d5d03f r7 0000008f 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime r8 b2d5d038 r9 99068f84 r10 99083a1c r11 b2d5d010 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime ip 9900ca7c sp b2d5d010 lr 9de33824 pc 9de33660 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime backtrace: 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime #00 pc 002fb660 /data/app/com.BananaBananaGamesStudio.PandaInLove-1/lib/arm/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: b5c43ddd04c71984469ca752577c033162526da7) 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime at libil2cpp.0x2fb660(Native Method)
```

I'm struggling for about two weeks on this: I made a game in the last months and it was running fine both on the editor and on my Android phone. I made more levels and implemented Unity Ads with no errors on the editor. But now it crashes in the first seconds at my Android device. But stills runs fine on the editor. With Unity Android Logcat I got this:

```
01/30 23:01:46.457 31856 31856 Error Zygote accessInfo : 0 01/30 23:01:47.137 31856 31869 Error CRASH *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** 01/30 23:01:47.137 31856 31869 Error CRASH Version '2020.3.23f1 (c5d91304a876)', Build type 'Release', Scripting Backend 'il2cpp', CPU 'armeabi-v7a' 01/30 23:01:47.137 31856 31869 Error CRASH Build fingerprint: 'samsung/j5lteub/j5lte:6.0.1/MMB29M/J500MUBU1BRD1:user/release-keys' 01/30 23:01:47.137 31856 31869 Error CRASH Revision: '5' 01/30 23:01:47.137 31856 31869 Error CRASH ABI: 'arm' 01/30 23:01:47.137 31856 31869 Error CRASH Timestamp: 2022-01-30 23:01:47-0300 01/30 23:01:47.137 31856 31869 Error CRASH pid: 31856, tid: 31869, name: UnityMain >>> com.BananaBananaGamesStudio.PandaInLove <<< 01/30 23:01:47.137 31856 31869 Error CRASH uid: 10172 01/30 23:01:47.137 31856 31869 Error CRASH signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0xb2d5cff8 01/30 23:01:47.137 31856 31869 Error CRASH
r0 9ef603b0 r1 b7c46bc8 r2 b7c46bc8 r3 b2d5d03e 01/30 23:01:47.137 31856 31869 Error CRASH r4 9ef48fb0 r5 0000011e r6 b2d5d03f r7 0000008f 01/30 23:01:47.137 31856 31869 Error CRASH r8 b2d5d038 r9 99068f84 r10 99083a1c r11 b2d5d010 01/30 23:01:47.137 31856 31869 Error CRASH ip 9900ca7c sp b2d5d010 lr 9de33824 pc 9de33660 01/30 23:01:47.137 31856 31869 Error CRASH 01/30 23:01:47.137 31856 31869 Error CRASH backtrace: 01/30 23:01:47.137 31856 31869 Error CRASH #00 pc 002fb660 /data/app/com.BananaBananaGamesStudio.PandaInLove-1/lib/arm/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: b5c43ddd04c71984469ca752577c033162526da7) 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error CRASH Tombstone written to: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.BananaBananaGamesStudio.PandaInLove/files/tombstone_02 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime FATAL EXCEPTION: UnityMain 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime Process: com.BananaBananaGamesStudio.PandaInLove, PID: 31856 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION [UnityMain] 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime Unity version : 2020.3.23f1 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime Device model : samsung SM-J500M 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime Device fingerprint: samsung/j5lteub/j5lte:6.0.1/MMB29M/J500MUBU1BRD1:user/release-keys 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime Build Type
: Release 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime Scripting Backend : IL2CPP 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime ABI : armeabi-v7a 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime Strip Engine Code : true 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime Caused by: java.lang.Error: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime Version '2020.3.23f1 (c5d91304a876)', Build type 'Release', Scripting Backend 'il2cpp', CPU 'armeabi-v7a' 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime Build fingerprint: 'samsung/j5lteub/j5lte:6.0.1/MMB29M/J500MUBU1BRD1:user/release-keys' 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime Revision: '5' 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime ABI: 'arm' 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime Timestamp: 2022-01-30 23:01:47-0300 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime pid: 31856, tid: 31869, name: UnityMain >>> com.BananaBananaGamesStudio.PandaInLove <<< 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime uid: 10172 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0xb2d5cff8 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime
r0 9ef603b0 r1 b7c46bc8 r2 b7c46bc8 r3 b2d5d03e 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime r4 9ef48fb0 r5 0000011e r6 b2d5d03f r7 0000008f 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime r8 b2d5d038 r9 99068f84 r10 99083a1c r11 b2d5d010 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime ip 9900ca7c sp b2d5d010 lr 9de33824 pc 9de33660 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime backtrace: 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime #00 pc 002fb660 /data/app/com.BananaBananaGamesStudio.PandaInLove-1/lib/arm/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: b5c43ddd04c71984469ca752577c033162526da7) 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime at libil2cpp.0x2fb660(Native Method)
```

If someone can point a light to help me I can't thank you enough. More Details: Unity Version: 2020.3.23f1 IL2CPP NET Standard 2.0 Minimum API 19 (4.4 KitKat) Target API 30 (11.0) My Android Device 6.01 (Marshmallow) ARMv7 and ARM64 both checked

Already tried with minimum and target to Marshmallow without success. Same results: crash on startup, not get into splash screen. Interesting facts: After clicking ok to the message "App crashed", the app still running in the background. And testing on an 11.0 Samsung Android phone results in a black screen. Also, the aab uploaded to google play store shows mostly black screens on the lab test and few crashs on few devices. I'm redoing from zero the project and slowly adding piece by piece again, and compiling, testing and recompiling every single addition, but has been a pain in the ass. I also did add the Ads system and it is working on the zero-project, so I believe has nothing to do with it. I'm using bolt to visual script a lot, and also did an AOT pre-build with the same (bad) results... Any help in where to go from here is much appreciated. I'm new to C# and Unity but I really try hard before asking for help. Thanks.

Comment: There is no useful information in the error log above.  Have you tried checking the Development Build check box in the build window? MAYBE, that would give you a more useful error log.

Comment: I add more log files from google play console with symbols uploaded. Gonna try your suggestion. Thanks a lot! @Fabio S.

Comment: I bought and installed your game to try to help.  The test ad runs fine, but there isn't much more going on at the moment. I could not do anything with the Panda. It is just there on the platform.  https://photos.app.goo.gl/nx3paTUpLW5a9yHq7

Comment: WOW! That's amazing, I really didn't expected that. The current version it is not the game, it is the version I am rebuilding from scratch, and since I thought the ads was the problem, I just implemented first. May I get your email to add you to the internal test where the full version is avaliable? If so, email me at bananabananagames@gmail.com . Anyway, your effort is much appreciated sir.

Comment: If not, I can upload the full version again on the open beta so you can test too. Thanks again!